# Is is possible to call function from another domain?

Tags: php, html

I have 2 domain and i want to move a php file from domain 1 to domain 2.
The purpose of the file is get user input, get data from database and etc.

The reason i want to do this is i dont want anyone can view the file in domain 1.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: really hard to understand this.

Comment: Very interesting, but your question is not clear. I can't understand it.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Example: When user input their id and password, my domain 1 will get the id and password and then pass the value to domain 2. Then domain 2 will go to database check whether the user is exist or not and return the result to domain 1.

Comment: domain 2 just has to have a script that listens (just like an API) for the post\get of the varaibles ,does it thing and returns true\false, domain 1 uses that to decide what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your data using cURL from your 2nd server to the PHP file in your 1st server and process the data there and then read the data sent back.

This is an example:

Assume: *example.org* is the domain of your your 1st server.

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.org/check.php");

$data = array(
    'username'      => 'JohnDoe',
    'password'      => '2hAreZ08npmv'
);

$data_json = json_encode($data); //Convert the array into a JSON string format


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $data_json );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch); //Returned value (echo) from the PHP file in your 1st server
```

Your 1st server will receive the username and password via [POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) method in JSON format. Like this:

```
{"username":"JohnDoe","password":"2hAreZ08npmv"}
```

Which you can decode and convert it to an array and use it in your function in the 1st server:

```
$data_received = "{"username":"JohnDoe","password":"2hAreZ08npmv"}";
$data_array = json_decode($data_received, true);
```

`echo` the result in the 1st server and you will receive it in `$result` variable that I used in the above code. The value of `$result` can be something like `'true'` or `'false'` or any other string that you `echo`.

This is a simple way to communicate between two servers using cURL in PHP.